# Область видимости файла с++

Tags: c++, терминология, область-видимости

У меня вопрос связанный с терминологией. Есть ли в с++ такое понятие, как `file-scope`?
Как лучше говорить `file-scope` или `translation-unit-scope`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Видимо таких не бывает.

В [списке scope](http://eel.is/c++draft/generalindex#:scope) из похожего есть только global scope и namespace scope.

Comment: Спасибо ща ответ, если я объявляю глобальную статическую переменную/функцию, я могу сказать, что она имеет область видимости единицы трансляции/файла?

Comment: @n1kzzz А чем это отличается от оригинального вопроса? Ответ тот же: я думаю, что таких областей видимости нет, и не слышал, чтобы кто-то использовал такие названия. Обычно про такие говорят namespace scope (даже если это глобальный неймспейс).

Comment: тоесть насколько я понимаю файл, это один большой `namespace`?

Comment: @n1kzzz *"про такие говорят namespace scope"* - Я имел в виду, про функции, объявленные снаружи классов. Файлы - не неймспейсы.